# Germany Job Offer Rejection

Tags: germany, resident-permit, self-employment

I reside in Germany with a self employment work permit. Recently I applied for a side job which was rejected, and they have sent me a deportation letter, saying that the job offer does not meet your qualification. But I wonder why they did not take into consideration my status as a self employed person and renew my residency on that basis?

This is a quote from the letter:
Notes: I particularly refer to Section 82 AufenthG (foreigner's obligation to cooperate). It is then your responsibility to assert your concerns and circumstances favorable to you without delay, stating verifiable circumstances, and to provide the necessary evidence of your personal circumstances, other required certificates and permits and other necessary evidence without delay. If the announced administrative order is associated with a threat of deportation, all reasons that stand in the way of deportation to the home country must be reported to the immigration authority and proven.

Comment: I'll suggest that it doesn't matter _why_ they didn't consider it. They just didn't. The letter you quote says that "...all reasons that stand in the way of deportation to the home country must be reported to the immigration authority and proven." Thus, you must now show and prove the "reasons that stand in the way of deportation" — i.e., your continued self-employment under permit — to the German immigration authority.

Comment: Do you meet all the relevant renewal criteria, eg proof of ‘secure livelihood’, and provide the right documentation?